# Which mouseover handler is better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, comparative-review

I'm currently learning some jQuery and I am stuck on something. On a small exercise I did, I was asked to perform an action when you mouseover a div class.  I gave a different solution than the one suggested and I was wondering which one is written best and why.

HTML code

```
<tr id ='user_1' class='datarow'>
   <td><input class='data' type='text' name='firstname' value='Firstname 1'></td>
   <td><input class='data' type='text' name='lastname' value='Lastname 1'></td>
   <td class='deletecell'><div class='success'></div></td>
</tr>
```

Here is my solution:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.success', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('success').addClass('delete');
});
```

And here is his solution:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.deletecell', function() {
    $('.success', this).addClass('delete').removeClass('success');
});
```

PS: Does it matter if `addClass` is first and `removeClass` is second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours is simpler and therefore better.  However, I would simplify it further as:

```
$('.success').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('success').addClass('delete');
});
```

Is shouldn't matter much whether you call `.addClass()` first or `.removeClass()` first.